# How to use LabelBinarizer for 2 label problem?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

If there are only 2 labels in the data, LabelBinarizer.fit_transform() returns array which has only a single column.

But for tensorflow model training for my usecase, what I need is 2 column in label array.
How can this be done with LabelBinarizer or is there any other API for it?OR do I need to manually modify the array by iterating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using TensorFlow, you can use [tf.keras.utils.to_categorical](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical).